# Is there a yekkish minhog regarding peyos?

Tags: minhag, ashkenazi, yekke, payot-sideburns

Is there a yekkish minhog regarding peyos?
Please cite sources.

Comment: Look at your profile pic. You can see that R' Hirsch זצ"ל tucked his (trimmed) peyos behind his ears. On the other hand, the Rawa"h had peyos something like what R' Lichtenstein זצ"ל wore (http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/08/portrait-of-wolf-heidenheim.html). I personally follow R' Hirsch's practice

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - See also [here](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/02/yekke-with-curly-peyos.html)

Comment: Does anyone have a copy of Shorshei Moreshes Ashkenaz they could look through and see if it says anything there?

Comment: @ezra There isn't anything about it in Shorshei Minhog Ashkenaz, unless it mentions it in the chapter on Upsherin.

Comment: @JoshuaPearl - Look there.

Comment: @I don't actually have it. I only know which topics are covered from the contents page on the KAYJ website https://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/1589-table-of-contents-for-shorshei-minhag-ashkenaz-i-iv